# Доступ к определёному набору папок и файлов Github

Tags: git, github

Добрый вечер, как мне организовать работу, чтобы мне хранить и иметь все ресурсы проекта в купленном приватном репозитории на Github и выдать доступ людям к определённым папкам и файлам.

К примеру, проект на С++ предоставить доступ к вшитым картинкам в бинарники (сами картинки вижу только я) и собраные dll'ки (исходники вижу тоже только я). Так же собираюсь организовать несколько sln файлов (всё, конкретная ветка(с собранными dll'ами)

К сожалению, раздел collaborators даёт доступ на чтение или на чтение/запись на весь репозиторий.

Проблема: сохранение интелектуального труда при "найме" джунов себе в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант создать отдельные репозитории для открытия доступа, а в своём проекте подключать их отдельно как расширения, например через  [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

Answer (score 1):

Недавно наткнулся на интересный инструмент - [blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) (кстати от создателей StackExchange). Суть в том, что "секретные" файлы хранятся в репозитории в зашифрованном виде и расшифровать его могут только пользователи с ключем. При зашифровке файла в список доступа добавляются публичные ключи пользователей, у которых будет доступ к файлу. Если список пользователей меняется - файл нужно перезашифровывать с новыми публичными ключами пользователей. При этом у удаленных пользователей доступ к старым ревизиям файла останется.

Как это выглядит для пользователя?

- Запустить агента для работы с ключами, если необходимо: `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`
- Расшифровать файл для редактирования: `blackbox_edit_start FILENAME` 
  (необходимо будет ввести пароль от ключа)
- Внести правки в файл: `vim FILENAME`
- Зашифровать файл: `blackbox_edit_end FILENAME`
- Закоммитить изменения: `git commit -a or hg commit`

---

*На своих проектах пока не использовал, поэтому сказать, удобно ли этим пользоваться на практике, не могу. Что сразу вызывает подозрение, так это просмотр диффов/истории и пул-реквесты.*

*Возможно в вашей ситуации можно создать несколько репозиториев с разным уровнем доступа для разных пользователей с соответствующими файлами в них. Но поддержка нескольких репозиториев с одной кодовой базой тоже дело не из приятных.*